# VSCode: Cannot Seem to Find Run Button to Run Javascript Code

Tags: button, visual-studio-code, execute

I have the following line of code that I want to run in my VSCode application.  I cannot find a Run button or option.  I think it should be on the top right corner.

It also looks like VSCode is not recognizing my code either.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check that you have the Code Runner extension enabled. The Extensions marketplace is accessible through the fifth button down on the toolbar.

[image: VSCode screenshot showing Extensions button]

If it is installed and enabled, you should see a Run button on the top-right of the tab bar.

Your code is not recognized because the file does not have a .js file extension. You can either change the extension so that it is recognized, or find the "Plain Text" indicator at the bottom-right in the status bar, and manually select "Javascript".

[image: VSCode screenshot showing language selector.]